# Weighted Random Item selection without replacement, drawn multiple times

Tags: google-sheets, random

I'm trying to build a system where I have a list of Items with weights associated with them. I want to randomly pull items from this pool, using their weights to determine chance of selection.

In the example spreadsheet, I have 10 fruits. I want to pull 3 fruits from the pool. The same fruit cannot be pulled more than once. These 3 fruits would be a fruit-selection.

I want to do this many times, across multiple rows, each providing a new random fruit-selection.

1. I've come across a couple of issues:

- Occasionally I've got this error:

  ```
  [Error
  Function INDEX parameter 2 value is 8. Valid values are between 0 and 7 inclusive.]
  ```
- Sometimes the formula for pulling an item results in an empty cell.

2. I'm probably not also doing this the most efficient way. I may need up to 300 rows of these 'fruit-selections'
3. Finally, I would like to determine the number of fruits being drawn to make up each fruit-selection. I've not hooked this up yet as I was trying to get the above working.

I'm hoping there's an efficient way of doing this. Maybe using sequence?

Appreciate any help / advice on this one.

[Spreadsheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1onr4pUsTvItKiQruuN0u8LVuBFRt4bw94rQY_iV1K6g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you ok with all results re-randomizing every time you refresh the sheet? If you want to avoid that, I think it would be convenient to use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) instead. Would you be ok with that?

Comment: I don't mind if the results randomize on every change

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you realize it but this is contra-productive... you can either have weights or unique values - not both of them because after you assign weights to your items it means that some of them will appear more frequently than the other ones. example:

let's say you want to choose 2 random items from this list

```
weight     item
_______________
4          mango
2          papaya
3          jackfruit
```

so you actually want to choose from this probability:

```
mango
mango
mango
mango
papaya
papaya
jackfruit
jackfruit
jackfruit
```

now as soon as you introduce "no duplicates" rule you are limiting your choice only to unique items so your choice will be reduced to:

```
mango
papaya
jackfruit
```

and at this point, you just lost the whole idea with weights which are just pointless because choosing two random items from the above list will yeild only 3 possible outcomes so the probability (weight) of choosing each item is 1:1:1 eg. the "weight" of 4 mangos becomes 1 mango

```
mango
papaya
```

---

```
papaya
jackfruit
```

---

```
mango
jackfruit
```

that being said... the selection of weighted random items would be like this:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SORT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(C2:C11&",", A2:A11),,9^9), ", ", 1)), 
 RANDARRAY(SUM(A2:A11)), ), "limit "&E2))
```

[image]

[image]

and selection of random non-repeating items would be done like this:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SORT(FILTER(C2:C11, C2:C11<>""), 
 RANDARRAY(COUNTA(C2:C11)), 1), "limit "&E2))
```

[image]

---

## update:

paste in H2:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SORT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(C2:C11&",", A2:A11),,9^9), ", ", 1)), 
 RANDARRAY(SUM(A2:A11)), ), "limit 1"))
```

paste in H3:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SORT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(C2:C11",", A2:A11),,9^9), ", ", 1)), 
 RANDARRAY(SUM(A2:A11)), ), "where Col1 <> '"&H2&"' limit 1"))
```

paste in H4 and drag down:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(QUERY(SORT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT($C$2:$C$11&",", $A$2:$A$11),,9^9), ", ", 1)), 
 RANDARRAY(SUM($A$2:$A$11)), ), "where not Col1 matches '"&
 JOIN("|", H$2:H3)&"' limit 1")))
```

and then use:

```
=OFFSET(H2:H,,,E2)
```

[image]

### [demo spreadesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zIrYsick-bcUg43zdhb0wJUvF7OiUIotGHJ_mAw-dRY/copy)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. The explanation is super clear and really helpful.

I still think I need a bit of both, so maybe I didn't explain properly.

Example:
When selecting 3 items:
- Apple has the highest weight, let's say that item is drawn.
- Now remove Apple as an option when drawing the second item. The next highest weight item is (tied: Banana, Cherries, Graps). Most likely one of them will get drawn.
- Item 2 is now removed from the list of possible items to draw for item 3.

Resulting fruit-selection (with highest probably outcome) is Apple, Banana, Cherries for example

Comment: You should (in theory) be able to get a weighted random draw without replacement. It's just that the normal way to get a random draw without dups is by sorting, but weighting doesn't work with that method. The only way I can think of at the moment is to make a selection using weighting, then filter the list to exclude the value(s) already drawn - but that would have to be a pull-across formula, not a single array formula.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's what I attempted at first.
Might have to go back to that method. Was a bit laboursome but maybe that's the only way.
Thanks

Comment: @TroyWilliams answer updated

Comment: I thought naively maybe you could divide the random number by the weights to get a weighted random number to sort on, but I think it isn't that simple. I'm trying to get my head round this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463561/weighted-random-selection-from-array which sounds promising.

Comment: This does not seem to be working for fruit names with spaces. Any thoughts? It seems to work then if we change the second ", " in the formula with ",", but then it doesn't work with 0 weights (for the last fruit?).

Comment: @TheCodingWombat can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result?