Assigning integer weights in Google Sheets
Given ’n’ random integer "values", how do we assign integer "weights" to each of these random "values" such that the weighted mean is also an integer.
Generating random integer "values" is not an issue. E.g. n= 4, yields {17, 9, 13, 8}.
As of now the "weights" are generated randbetween(1,10) each, for example {10,8,4,4} resulting in a non-integer mean of 12 7/13.
How do we generate the "weights" so that the mean is also an integer?

You need to make sure the sum of those 4 numbers is a multiple of 4

Is this an XY problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304250/5632629

A brute-force search like this?
=ArrayFormula(let(values,A2:A5,weights,lambda(self,v,let(w,int(randarray(rows(values))*10)+1,if(mod(sumproduct(w,v)/sum(w),1)=0,w,self(self,v)))),weights(weights,values)))


or excluding duplicate weights, then:
=ArrayFormula(let(values,A2:A5,weights,lambda(self,v,let(w,array_constrain(sort(sequence(10),randarray(10),1),rows(values),1),if(mod(sumproduct(w,v)/sum(w),1)=0,w,self(self,v)))),weights(weights,values)))


If the weights didn't have to be random, then trying the smallest first would be a good strategy e.g. {1,1,1,2} if duplicates are allowed with an average of 11.

Thank You so much Sir (Mr. Sharpe). Your method works for me. Yes, randomness is a requirement, and duplicates are acceptable.

Glad it worked for you. Plz consider upvoting/accepting answer if it's useful. I don't know how you would estimate the probability of a random selection of weights producing an integer average, but a quick simulation gave it as somewhere around 1 in 50 for these particular values.
