# Random selection, weighted by rank

Tags: algorithm, random

Let's say I have a collection of *n* objects, and that each object has a ranking associated with it, and these rankings correspond to the integer values 1 through *n*.

Now suppose that I want to select an object at random from the collection. But I don't want to just pick a number from 1 to *n* at random; instead I want to make it so that I am more likely to pick a number higher up the list (with a ranking closer to 1).

**Proposed solution:** Instead of picking from 1 to *n*, pick from 1 to *m*, where *m* is some number significantly larger than *n*; then use some mapping function *f* : [1,*m*] → [1,*n*] that maps more numbers to the higher rankings than to the lower rankings. For instance, *f*(1), *f*(2), *f*(3) might all return 1, while *f*(m) is the only one which maps to *n*, so it is three times more likely to get 1 than *n*. Hopefully that makes sense.

So my question is: If this seems like a reasonable algorithm, what's a reasonable function *f* that accomplishes this, and what ratio *m/n* would be large enough that integer rounding doesn't prevent numbers from never getting picked?

[In my particular scenario, *n* can be pretty large (in the thousands), so solutions like the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/352670/436282) aren't very practical for this situation. Also, the selection is "with replacement"; i.e. I pick an object once and then return; I don't care if I pick it again immediately the next time.]

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761626/weighted-random-numbers/1761646#1761646

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
double bias = 1.5; 
int index = (int)(n * (bias - sqrt(bias*bias -4.0*(bias-1.0)* random()))
                  / 2.0 / (bias-1));
```

Changing the bias parameter lets you control how strongly you favor the higher ranked individuals.

Edit: Here's some python code for it.

```
def pick(n, bias):
    return int(n * (bias - sqrt(bias*bias -4.0*(bias-1.0)*random())) / 2.0 / (bias-1))

vals = [0]*10
for i in xrange(1000):
    vals[pick(10,1.5)] += 1
print vals
[153, 151, 115, 116, 97, 96, 87, 69, 66, 50]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come up with this formula? I don't doubt it works, but it's not immediately obvious to me as to *why* it works.

Comment: I didn't. My advisor in grad school had developed an algorithm that needed to do this years ago (1989 to be exact, and the algorithm is a GA called Genitor). I recognized the same requirements and pulled up the code to that algorithm. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using the normal random approach (`random.uniform(0, 1)`), but squaring the probability.

Since `P{x}` ranges from `0 -> 1`, P{x^2}`also ranges from`0 -> 1`.

But the weight is uneven, as a small number squared is still small, and a larger number squared becomes small.

Just a thought.

Comment: This is a great idea... in fact, any function x^y would work on the range from 0 to 1 since 0^y=0 and 1^y=1 for all y.

Comment: You have quite a lot of choices ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is function *f* : [1,*n*] → **N** (the natural numbers 0, 1, 2, ...).  This would assign a weighting to each rank.  Then you want to pick rank *k* with probability *f*(*k*) / (Σ *f*(*i*)), in other words, that rank's weight over the sum of the weights of all ranks.  To do that, you can simply pick an integer uniformly at random over the interval [1, Σ *f*(*i*)] and figure out what rank you are in based on your position; if you are in 1 ... *f*(1), pick 1, if you are in *f*(1)+1 ... *f*(1)+*f*(2), pick 2, and so forth.

One possible choice for *f* which weights small ranks higher than big ranks is *f*(*i*) = *n* - *i* + 1.  There are many other possible choices.

Answer (score 1):

Generate K random numbers from the interval 1..n (K > 1) and choose the minimum!

This has the properties you want, check out a demonstration of the distributions at http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/samplemin.htm

To make this work with fractional values of K (1 < K < 2) you can do it like this:

```
int m = random_int(1..n)
if (random_double(0..1) <= K - 1):
     m = min(m, random_int(1..n))
```

So when K approaches 1 from above the distribution becomes more and more flat.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, although I think the curve for K = 2 might even be too steep for my needs.

Comment: Ok, added an explanation how to do it for fractional values 1 < K < 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Normalize by rank, then build a binary tree. Select a random double and find the corresponding value.