# Weighted random selection using Walker's Alias Method

Tags: c#, .net, f#, probability

I was looking for this algorithm 
***(algorithm which will randomly select from a list of elements where each element has different probability of being picked (weight) )***
and found only python and c implementations, after I did a C# one, a bit different (but I think simpler) I thought I should share it, also I need an **F# imlementation**, if anyone can make it please post an answer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ChuckNorris
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var oo = new Dictionary<string, int>
                         {
                             {"A",7},
                             {"B",1},
                             {"C",9},
                             {"D",8},
                             {"E",11},
                         };

            var rnd = new Random();
            var pick = rnd.Next(oo.Values.Sum());

            var sum = 0;
            var res = "";

            foreach (var o in oo)
            {
                sum += o.Value;
                if(sum >= pick)
                {
                    res = o.Key;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("result is "+  res);
        }
    }
}
```

**if anyone can remake it in F# please post your code**

Comment: If you have an answer to a question, it's generally considered good practice to ask the question and then respond to the question yourself (but not by adding the answer in the question). See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this Walker's alias method, but it is not even remotely close to that method. Indeed you require O(N) to pick one out of N element, when the alias method allows you to draw a random object in O(1) time by creating a two-line array.

Comment: @Jeremie I was looking for this for some time, and found only python implementation which I don't understand, but after reading the intro for those codes I got to this, which actually worked

Comment: @Chuck Norris, yes it does work and it's probably more practical like that... but it's much, much slower than if you were using something like the actual Alias Method, because you have to go through the whole dictionary every time you make a random selection. Think of it as the difference between looking up an element in an unsorted list, and in a hash table.

Comment: @Jeremie do you have a c#/f# implementation of the actual Walker alias method ?

Comment: Here is a Ruby implementation: https://github.com/cantino/walker_method

Comment: This is **NOT** walkers alias method. This requires O(n) time to complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the similar code in F#:

```ml
let rng = new System.Random()
let d = [| "A", 3
           "B", 2
           "C", 3 |]
let sums = Seq.scan (+) 0 (dict d).Values |> Seq.skip 1 |> Seq.toArray 
let pick = rng.Next(sums.[sums.Length-1])
let res = fst d.[sums |> Seq.findIndex ((<) pick)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```ml
open System

let oo = dict [ "A", 7;
                "B", 1;
                "C", 9;
                "D", 8;
                "E", 11 ]

let rnd = Random()
let pick = oo.Values |> Seq.sum |> rnd.Next

let res = oo |> Seq.scan (fun (_, s) (KeyValue(k, v)) -> k, s + v) ("", 0)
             |> Seq.tryPick (fun (k, s) -> if s >= pick 
                                           then printfn "Result is %s" k; Some k 
                                           else None)
```