# code for choosing N values with some associated probabilities

Tags: python, algorithm, probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a set `x` of `N` values `{x_i; i=1,...,N}` and a set of some associated probabilities `{w_i; i=1,...,N}`.

We want to get from the set `x`, a new set `x^` of `N` values `{x^_i; i=1,...,N}` by choosing each value `x_i` from the set`x` according to the probability `w_i`. How do we code that (i.e. a pseudo code algorithm, that can be translated to any language).

EDIT: python code:

```
def resample(self,x,w):
    N = len(w)
    new_x = empty(N)
    c = cumsum(w)

    for i in range(N):
        r = random()
        for j in range(N):
            if( j == N-1 ):
                new_x[i] = x[j]
                break
            else:
                if( (c[j] <= r) and (r < c[j+1]) ):
                    new_x[i] = x[j+1]
                    break

    new_w = ones(N,dtype=float)/N
    return new_x, new_w
```

Comment: what's the relationship between `x_i` and `w_i`? What do you mean "according to the probability `w_i`"?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352670/weighted-random-selection-with-and-without-replacement

Comment: @user995434 Regardless of whether or not it's homework, questions on SO are meant to show effort on the part of the asker. SO is not a place to get people to do it all for you, whether 'it' is homework or not. All you have said is 'I need this'.

Comment: @NateKohl I've added a python code, can you check if it is correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call a function which gives you a random number between 0 and 1.
If the probabilities are w_1 = 0.2, w_2 = 0.5, w_3 = 0.3, you can:
Choose x_1 if you got a number between 0 and 0.2
Choose x_2 if you got a number between 0.2 and 0.7
Choose x_3 otherwise.

More generally, choose x_n if w_1 + ... + w_(n-1) <= random number < w_1 + ... + w_(n-1) + w_n

That's not the whole pseudocode, just an explanation of its most problematic part, but I think it should be enough if you have a basic understanding of your problem.

Comment: I've added a python code, can you check if it is correct according to what you explained ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is preprocessing the probability set and then getting a random value.

Let me explain what I mean:

First you create a new set, for example h_i in which you place the accumulated probability of each object.

```
x_i:{A,B,C,D}
w_i:{0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1}
h_i:{0.2,0.5,0.9,1}
```

The last element is of course 1. (but if it is not (you have missing cases) it still works.

Now you generate a random number 0≤r≤1 and lookup the first element whose h is greater than r.

For example if you get 0.56 you choose C because 0.9(h_C) > 0.56 and 0.5(h_B) ≤ 0.56

This operation can be expensive on arrays but if you choose a binary search tree for the storage of the set h_i you can get very good results.

That is  if you want to choose lots of random values over the same probability set. If the set is constantly changing I would use another approach.

Comment: I've added a python code, can you check if it is correct according to what you explained ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# import the random library
import random

# define the input data
X = ["A","B","C","D"]
w = [0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1]

# size of the new sample
n = 10

# empy list to store the result
Xp = []

# the actual code
while len(Xp) < n:
    random_choice = random.choice(w)
    if random_choice >= random.random():
        Xp.append(X[w.index(random_choice)])

# have a look
Xp
```

Out[39]:

['C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'B']