# Get random element by given priority

Tags: python, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weighted random selection with and without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352670/weighted-random-selection-with-and-without-replacement)

I tired to make all decisions what to do next by myself. I want computer to do it. 
I only write things and give priority to each, computer selects one by these priorities with random element.

So, I made this file (tsv):

```
3   work A
2   work B
1   work C
1   laundry
1   nothing
```

"Work A" should happens with 38% probability. "nothing" - 13%, etc.
Computer should count all this and say to me: `do ___`

I can read it and get percents for each thing. But I cannot figure out how should I select one thing with these percents.

```
import csv

# reading
file = open('do.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
tsv_file = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')

# total priority
priority_total = 0
for work in tsv_file:
    priority_total = priority_total + int(work[0])

?????

print(do_this)
```

What is the way to do this? Is there a function for random selection with given probabilities?

I really need this to stop procrastinating and start doing things.

Comment: I like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3679747/487339).

Comment: didn't know that is "weighted"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a simple approach would be to create a list of your tasks, but add each task a number of times to the list equal to its priority.

So after loading your file, the list would look like this:

```
['work A', 'work A', 'work A', 'work B', 'work B', 'work C', 'laundry', 'nothing']
```

and then you can use [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) to select a random element.

```
task_list = []
for prio, work in tsv_file:
    task_list += [work] * int(prio)

do_this = random.choice(task_list)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this until I realized there might be a better solution in the duplicate.

Comment: thanks, so easy to get it. Finally I will start doing things now. Just need to mess a little with priorities and tasks )